# How to send potentially large data through spring websockets without memory issues

Tags: java, spring, websocket

I need to send multiple files with metadata from one server to another remote server.

I was previously accomplishing this by using Spring `MultiPartFile`s, which allowed me to attach small `File` handles to perform the transfer without having to load the file into memory while also performing chunked transfers.

I'm now unable to perform two-way `http` communication due to issues beyond my control, which has led me to explore Spring `websocket`s (one way http is fine and I believe that I can communicate over the socket without issues).

The primary issue that I'm facing has been the extra performance/memory cost in reading some potentially large files just to send them off.  This wasn't an issue with `MultiPartFile`s because they didn't actually need to read data into memory on either the receiving or sending side.  And if I'm sending multiple files with a single transfer then it's even worse.

Comment: Why not use a BufferedReader? Seems like exactly what it was made for

Comment: @MatthewKerian I was hoping that `Spring` had some built-in way to handle this issue, with how common it must be, that wouldn't result in me needing to hand-roll asynchronous code to piece socket frames together to multiple files.  Just kinda seems like something a big framework like Spring should already have figured out, since they already do that for `MultiPartFile`s.

Comment: Ah, unfortunately I don't have enough experience to comment on that.